# Using GeometryReader in SwiftUI I can not display on the each cell of a LazyVGrid the items of a string vector

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am writing a code to display on canvas the items of a String vector called items.

I tried to change the sizes of frame or to remove it but again I do not receive what I want. This is the code:

```
struct example1: View {
    let rows: Int = 4
    let columns: Int = 4
    let items: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: columns), spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(items.indices) { index in
                    Text(items[index])
                   
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/CGFloat(columns), height: geometry.size.height/CGFloat(rows))
                        .position(x: getFrame(for: index, in: geometry, rows: rows, columns: columns).midX,
                                   y: getFrame(for: index, in: geometry, rows: rows, columns: columns).midY)
                        .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                        .background(Color.white)

                }
            }
            .frame(width: 400, height: 800)
        }
    }

    func getFrame(for index: Int, in geometry: GeometryProxy, rows: Int, columns: Int) -> CGRect {
        let row = index / columns
        let column = index % columns
        let width = geometry.size.width / CGFloat(columns)
        let height = geometry.size.height / CGFloat(rows)
        let x = CGFloat(column) * width
        let y = CGFloat(row) * height
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I obtain a CGRect with 4x4 cells, but I do not see the letters inside each cell. Moreover, I receive the error "Non-constant range: not an integer range" in the ForEach loop, and I do not understand why. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure, this is entire code:

Comment: [edit] your question to include the relevant code. Do not add it an answer

Comment: In SwiftUI it is generally a bad idea to use `GeometryReader` and fixed sizes for items. It is better to let the layout engine handle all of this for you. Using the LazyVGrid should be all that is required

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI you should use `GeometryReader` and frame calculations as a last resort.  It is nearly always better to simply describe what you want and let the layout engine deal with things.

It is also a good idea to use sub view structures rather than trying to use dozens of modifiers on a view.

Start by describing an item view:

```
struct ItemView: View {
    var content: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().fill(.background)
                .border(.primary)
            Text(content)
        }.aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0), contentMode: .fill)
    }
}
```

This is a white rectangle with a black border with some text on top of the rectangle.

The view should be square (aspect ratio of 1:1) and fill the available space.

Note that I have used `.background` and `.primary` colours rather than white and black - This allows the view to automatically adapt to light and dark mode on the device.

Now, we can use the `LazyVGrid` to layout a series of these. We only need to specify that we want 4 columns and then the grid will take care of everything for us.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let columns: Int = 4
    let items: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P"]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: columns), spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                ItemView(content: item)
            }
        }.padding()
    }  
}
```

This is the result on an iPhone 14 Pro max and an iPhone SE:

[image] [image]

See how the views adapt to the device size automatically

Also, note that there was no need to use an `index` - Again, this is something of a "code smell" in SwiftUI.  If you find yourself needing to know an index, you may want to take another look at your solution.